# Area of Study for Four dimensional Space

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, low-dimensional-topology, 4-manifolds

I wanted to know which area in Mathematics involves study of objects in 4d, geometry and other parameters in 4d space; that involves more of imagining objects in 4d ? As of now, I am aware of Topology, Abstract Algebra, Measure theory, Differential Equations and Linear Algebra stuff. What course can I choose next for moving on to research in 4d spaces ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a walk through the book **The Geometry of Four Manifolds** of S.K. Donaldson and P.B. Kronheimer from 1990   which requires a firm knowledge on differential topology.

Comment: Okay. Does 4 dimensional study comes in differential topology ?

Comment: differential topology is employ to develop 4-manifolds knowledge